# Least expensive blog reply system

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb

I have a simple user bulletin board, which lists the posts in chronological order.  What is the least expensive method, best practice, to add a reply system to the board?  Right now, I just query the posts, sorted by `-date`, and send to the template.  To add each post's replies, should I:

Make the replies children of another post, using ndb.KeyProperty or add the ancestor to its key? 
Give the replies an `in_reply_to` field?
Give the original post a list of reply keys?
etc

I want to minimize reads and writes.  I want to simply list one level deep:

```
Post 1
  -Reply 1
  _Reply 2
Post 2
  -Reply 1
  -Reply 2
  -etc.
```

Thank you for your opinions.

Comment: The answer will depend to an extent on your consistency requirements.  For example, do you want a reply to be available immediately after posting, by querying replies for a post?

Comment: Well, of course no one WANTS inconsistencies, but they are acceptable.  We live with them now in the original posts.  Next will be some sort of Ajax refresh scheme, to make the inconsistencies less noticeable to the user.

Comment: The main inconsistency that tx802 is probably referring to is eventual consistency. The issue here is that if you do *not* keep all replies in a single entity group (for example having them all have their post as a parent), a query for the replies to a post may change between calls. This is a fundamental limit of the underlying datastore -- using ajax to get replies cannot change this unless you structure your replies to be strongly consistent. Keep in mind though that this would limit replies to a post to ~1 response (per post) per second.

Comment: One response per post per second is acceptable.  What are the advantages/disadvantages of each method?